# Start WPF application with WinForms window

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml, windows

I have `WPF` application with some `WPF` windows. But my main window is `WinForms` and I need to start program with it. But how can I do this? This is my `App.xaml` file:

```
<Application x:Class="Player.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="UI/MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

If I try to replace `StartupUri="UI/MainWindow.xaml"` with `StartupUri="UI/Form1.cs"`, I get `"System.IO.IOException", "Cannot find "ui/form1.cs"`. Is it even possible to start my app with `WinForms` window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First go to App.xaml and remove `StartupUri="UI/MainWindow.xaml"`.
Than go to App.xaml.cs and override OnStartup method. In there you can instantiate and run your win forms window.

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
    var form = new Form1();
    form.Show();
}
```

Comment: Now I have a problem: my `OnExit` method is not called, when I close the window. How can I fix this?

Comment: @JustLogin Create a public method in any xaml.cs that calls Application.Current.Shutdown(). Call that from Form1.FormClosed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good article from MSDN which provides you an example how to integrate an Windows-Forms element in XAML: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms742875(v=vs.110).aspx

It should be helpful for your suppose.

Comment: It's not working for me. Yes, I know about `WindowsFormsHost` class, but it has a problem. Since my app is a media player at it main, I'm using `axwindowsmediaplayer` to play video (`MediaElement` is not a solution due to poor performance). It works fine, but start lagging when hosted in WPF.